# Fibonacci Sequence with vectors

Tags: c++, stdvector, fibonacci

I'm currently trying to solve some problems of the Euler-Projects, but I'm currently stuck at the second problem. Here is what I have right now:

```
void p002()
{
    unsigned int result = 0;    
    std::vector<int> fibonacci{ 1,2 };

    for (int i = 2; fibonacci.at(i) < 4000000; i++)
    {
        fibonacci.at(i) = fibonacci.at(i - 1) + fibonacci.at(i - 2); //<- Doesn't work
        if (fibonacci.at(i) % 2 == 0)
            result += fibonacci.at(i);
    }

    std::cout << result;
}
```

Could someone help me out and tell me why this one line doesn't seem to work? (I get an "abort() called" error when trying to execute the code.)

In case anyone wonders: The task is to get the sum of all integers of the fibonacci sequence with a lower value than 4,000,000 which are even-valued.

Thanks!

Comment: vector's can't resize themselves without you calling the appropriate function(s).  That should be enough information to let you know what could be the problem.  Second, this is a one-liner using `std::accumulate` and [Binet's formula](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html#section1)

Comment: *The task is to get the sum of all integers of the fibonacci sequence with a lower value than 4,000,000 which are even-valued.* -- Also, you don't need vector to solve the problem if you used the formula above in the comment, and just loop, adding to a total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector::at` throws an exception if you try to access an element at an index that is out of bounds. Your vector contains 2 elements (at indices 0 and 1). Therefore `fibonacci.at(2)` is out of bounds, and an exception is thrown. You don't catch the exception, so `std::terminate` is called. By default, `std::terminate` points to `abort` which terminates your process.

Solution: Add enough elements into the vector so that `fibonacci.at(i)` isn't out of bounds.